# webkit browsers on css:fixed and flash object

Tags: css, flash, object, jwplayer, css-position

the website im currently coding has a fixed header element. it includes the navigation etc. and stays in the top area of the site, even if you scroll. also the website has a background-image and since the header is partly transparent, the background image is also inside the header, to cover the content below it. now this works fine, until the content includes a flash object. if so, and you scroll down and the object hits the fixed header, the background image of the header gets strangefully repositioned. i have no explaination for this. this only happens on webkit.

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/jAJfc/1/) and make sure to use mac safari/chrome or win chrome

i took the code from my rendered website, the object gets generated by the jwplayer. they have no explaination for that eather.

both image container have following css class

```
.back {
    background: url(../img/back_img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem lies in the 'fixed' setting in the background for .back. Omit the fixed and the image stays. Not sure if that solves it for you.

Comment: the value fixed makes sure that both elements, the actual background and the header including the background, have the exact same postion. if you change that attribute to scroll (default), the both images have different starting points, so if the lay on another, you see its two images. it should appear as one image.